# Get Userrule by email in asp.net mvc 5 when try to login (when user is not logged in)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }


        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email,    model.Password,model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var UserID= from u in db.Users
                    where u.Email == model.Email
                    select u.Id;
 var RolesForUser = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(UserID);


    }
```

"Attention=>User is not logged in. i want user id by email when user try to login.I do query and get UserID bur Exception came as UserID is null"

Comment: `db.Users` should have all the information you need.

Comment: But user not logged in .so when user logged in then "db.Users" will contain all information.But i want user id when user enter email and press submit. Then i find userid by email and then by userId i find rulename.

Comment: `var UserInfo= from u in db.Users
                    where u.Email == model.Email
                   ;` what are you getting in userInfo? Ideally there should be model for roles too

Comment: I know roles table.In "UserInfo" i want only id

Comment: What you mean by userId? the asp.net membership has `id` column for the user's id by default

Comment: You should get it in `UserID` else assume your email is wrong!

Comment: when i debug UserID then it contain "id".But when used in var RolesForUser = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(UserID); An Exception come as "UserID " is Null.